# Laravel login and redirect after registration fails

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, registration

Im just trying to make a new user, log that user in, send a verification email and redirect to the user dashboard where the "you need to verify your user" messages is. It works up until the redirect, where it suddenly fails. In the "auth" middleware it tells me that the user is not logged in for some reason, but it works in the registration controller. This is my registration controller function.

```
public function store(RegisterUserRequest $request)
    {
        $user = new User();
        $user->name = $request->name;
        $user->email = $request->email;
        $user->password = bcrypt($request->password);
        $user->points = 0;
        $user->role_id = UserRole::USER;
        $user->verified = $request->verified ?? 0;
        $user->verify_email_code = Str::random(30);

        $user->save();

        $userdata = [
            'email'     => $request->email,
            'password'  => $request->password
        ];
        if (Auth::attempt($userdata)) {
            //send user to user dashboard
            return redirect()->route('users.show');
        } else {
            // login not successful, send back to form
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors(__("messages.innloging-mislykkes"));
        }
    }
```

I have tried redirecting to an action, redirecting to the view directly and so on. I suspect the session is not persisting.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/hashing#hashing-passwords recommends using `Hash::make` to hash the password, so that it matches the Auth attempt. `bcrypt()` probably means the password doesn't match

Comment: I tried dumping the user after the attempted login, and it works there, just not after the redirect. Changed it to Hash::make just to make sure, and still the same error

Comment: hi, where is the verification mail you talk about in the controller? Also, you said the ```if (Auth::attempt($userdata)) {``` is successful  and it fails to redirect to users.show? if that s the case showing the web.php file may help

Comment: you don't need to call `attempt` you already have the user object, `$user` ... `Auth::login($user)`

Comment: Hi, I removed it before posting here to make sure it did not interfer with the redirect. It didn't have any effect.

Comment: `Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/min-side', [UserController::class, 'show'])->name('users.show');
});`

Here is the web.php code